# How to place an element at the left and right side of overflowing div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I will be making the arrows clickable to scroll left/right in the div

I have a div which contains a bunch of elements (arrows are not included in the div for my method) [as seen here](https://gyazo.com/454c04ff5b8de1102c0836a7759379d6)

I want to align the arrows as seen in the image, however these are not responding as expected when the page is a different size due to the terrible method I have wrote.. what would be the best way to do the above?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
<img src={arrowLeft} alt="Left Arrow" className="arrow"></img>
      <div className="gridRow">
         ......content for elements here.......
      </div>
<img src={arrowRight} alt="Right Arrow" className="arrow right"></img>
```

And the CSS:

```
/*Arrow images*/
.arrow {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 121%;
}

.arrow.right {
  left: 91.7%;
}

.arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving `position: absolute` to the two arrows (which will make them unresponsive to screen changes), you could just wrap everything inside a `div` and give the `div` the following CSS properties:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center.
```

This way, all the elements will be in a row and vertically centered.

Comment: Will try this shortly, thanks! I can't imagine this method failing